# How to Hide Code cells When converting a Jupyter Notebook into Sphinx Doc using nbsphinx

Tags: jupyter-notebook, python-sphinx

I'm new to Sphinx documentation, and I am trying to convert a Jupyter Notebook into Sphinx docs using Nbsphinx. Especially, I want to hide the code cells (not their outputs), but I could not make it using templates that I found for Jupyter Nbconvert.

I expect the outputs from converted notebook on the Sphinx documentation, but no input.

Comment: Hi, KYigit! Can you post the code you've tried so far?

Comment: Hello, thank you so much for the prompt reply. Hre is the tpl code I use in "source/_templates" directory.                                                                       {%- extends 'full.tpl' -%}

{% block input_group -%}
<div class="input_hidden">
{{ super() }}
</div>
{% endblock input_group %}

Answer (score 2):

I added the following code to the first cell and it works well.

```
import IPython.core.display as di # Example: di.display_html('<h3>%s:</h3>' % str, raw=True)
di.display_html('<script>jQuery(function() {if (jQuery("body.notebook_app").length == 0) { jQuery(".input_area").toggle(); jQuery(".prompt").toggle();}});</script>', raw=True)'
```

Comment: I have [the exact same issue](https://github.com/spatialaudio/nbsphinx/issues/285#issuecomment-543350301), but I don't really understand how to implement your answer. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Of Course, you just add the code beginning with "import IPython....." to the first cell. Please note that you could use ''' instead of '. What this does is when the Sphinx runs it hides the code cell using java script.

Comment: You have no idea on how precious this is. Thank you!